# Magento Bundle Product Price Different in Product View Page and Search Result Page

Tags: magento-1.9, price, bundled-product

I have search the bundle product in my site.

That bundle product shown price is **"As low as: £783.00"** in that **search result page**.

Then I clicked that bundle product it goes to the **product view page**.

That page shown price is **"As low as: £461.25"**.

I have enabled the path hintes both page the product price render below Block and Template :

> **Block** : Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_Price
>
> **Template** : frontend/[XXX]/[YYY]/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml

Why is the price shown differently?

***Screen Shot - 1 : Product View Page :***
[image]

***Screen Shot - 2 : Search Result Page :***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have said, this looks like the search indexes need to be re-indexed. This can be done either through the admin panel under System > Index Management or on the command line with indexer.php (see http://inchoo.net/magento/executing-magento-indexer-from-shell/ for a good writeup).

I would suggest, particularly if you have a lot of products, running the indexes individually and starting with the search indexers. This will mitigate some of the performance issues that can occur while the indexes are running if running on live.

Also note that after re-indexing, it would be wise to clear the cache as well under System > Cache Management > Select All > Refresh